# Prevent user input data from getting lost when adding another tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I am dynamically adding tabPanels to a tabsetPanel. However, to add a tab I am recreating the entire tabsetPanel and this also deletes all the data the user has already entered. In the example code, when some choice has been made for selectInput on tab 1 and then the Add Tab button is clicked, the choice on tab 1 is gone.

Is there an easier / better way to add a tab without losing the user input than storing it before and re-setting it after the new tabsetPanel has been generated?

(Is it possible to "manipulate" the tabsetPanel in order to add another tab?)

```
library(shiny)

TSTAddin <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage( 
    actionButton('addTab','Add Tab'),
    uiOutput('panelset')
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$panelset <- renderUI({
      panL <- lapply(1:(input$addTab + 1), function(x) {tabPanel(paste0('Pan',x), selectInput(paste0('in',x), label=x, choices=LETTERS[1:10]))})
      do.call(tabsetPanel, panL)
    })
  }

  viewer <- paneViewer(300)
  runGadget(ui, server, viewer = viewer)
}
TSTAddin()
```